# Linux Buddy page frames allocation and freeing

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

While reading and understanding linux kernel using the guide-
http://www.johnchukwuma.com/training/UnderstandingTheLinuxKernel3rdEdition.pdf

I have something I'm trying to understand in the Buddy system for page allocaion and freeing.

> The technique adopted by Linux to solve the external fragmentation
> problem is based on the well-known buddy system algorithm. All free
> page frames are grouped into 11 lists of blocks that contain groups of
> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, and 1024 contiguous page
> frames, respectively. *[chapter 8.1.7]*

This makes perfectly sense as now Linux can serve allocation request quickly as there are different chunk sizes ready for different chunk sizes requests.

Now, say the system starts up, and with all the available pages are free and grouped as mentioned above to those 11 groups. Now lets consider a scenario in which a process requires one page of order 1, then free it. According to the free algorithm-

```
while (order < 10)
{ 
     buddy_idx = page_idx ^ (1 << order);
     buddy = base + buddy_idx;
     if (!page_is_buddy(buddy, order))
         break;
     list_del(&buddy->lru);
     zone->free_area[order].nr_free--;
     ClearPagePrivate(buddy);
     buddy->private = 0;
     page_idx &= buddy_idx;
     order++;
 }
```

so according to this and my scenario, the order 1 chunk (the first ever allocated) will be merged with another order 1 chunk into a chunk of order 2, though the two order 1 chunks have not been splitted from an order 2 chunk in allocation stage.

This way, if I keep on allocate and then free a single chunk, pretty quickly the system will reach a state in which all memory chunks are of the biggest order, which seems not efficient. I would have expected that merging two buddies will be made only when those buddies were previously splitted from a bigger order chunk, that way the initial default state will be preserved as much as possible and the whole system will be kept efficient.

Am I missing something? is it possible that this code is wrong? am I not aware of another advantage this code provides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption of such an *initial* state when plenty of smallest order blocks are available might be slightly dubious. If I recall correctly, allocation of a memory block should commence with looking at the smallest (the same size) group and then looking at greater-order groups to find a free block. If the block found is larger than needed, it will be split, and the corresponding groups will be updated. It's not so obvious, but this whole process might commence with the initial state when only highest-order blocks are available.

A handful of examples which I can meet in the literature draw almost the same picture of the initial state. An eloquent example may be found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation#In_practice . The diagram and the description shed some light on a typical situation.

All in all, I can't find any proof for the assumption of the "initial default state". The idea of decrease in efficiency when splitting a smaller chunk from a larger one is the most murky and probably deserves a separate talk.

**EDIT**:

The *initial* state from the kernel's point of view might not be the same as the initial state seen by your hypothetical process. Say, the system starts, and at certain point there is one chunk of memory. However, your hypothetical process will not be alone, - for sure. The memory distribution will likely change a lot *before* the process will be able to begin allocating and freeing any chunks of memory. For sure, the kernel or, to be precise, most of its subsystems will request plenty of memory chunks of different sizes during initialisation, and significant amount of the chunks will be owned by the kernel for considerable amount of time (perhaps, throughout the whole uptime). So, the point is that by the time your process starts, the buddy system will likely be "warmed up" and, indeed, enough small chunks will be available. However, the *buddies* for the pages (acquired by your process) will still be owned by various subsystems, and, as soon as your process decides to free *its* pages, those *buddies* will not be approved as ready for merge, i.e. `page_is_buddy()` from the excerpt will yield false. Of course, this whole scenario might be true provided that your process indeed succeeds to take *existing* free chunks without splitting higher-order blocks.

So, the point is that your assumption of the *initial* buddy distribution might not be the *true initial state*. It could only be a "warmed up" state where you indeed may have small chunks *but* their *buddies* will be busy and thus shall prevent the described hypothetical process of uncontrollable merge.

P.S. Here is the [description](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L731) of what `page_is_buddy()` is for.

Comment: your example depict even less efficient approach. Lets take the scenario of allocating a single memory chunk of the smallest size and then free it, while system is in its initial state when memory is one chunk. The allocation will consume much effort to devide all memory to all memory chunks sizes in order to reach the smallest chunk size to satisfy the allocation, then the free will also consume much effort with respect to the algorithm in Linux I presented in my question, as every pair of chunks of size X will be merged to 2X chunk size, starting from smallest size to biggest.

Comment: I see your concern, however, this still might be not quite accurate picture. Please see the edit in my post.